# storing value from text input into redux store cause re-rendering react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to store value from text input into the redux store but problem is that my react component is still re-rendering.

After dispatching action using debounce action, the component Autocomplete rerender and I get initial state. So input become empty after 300ms because of debounce func.

I tried to use **useCallback** to avoid it but without any result.

How Could I save input value into redux store and prevent re-render react component ?

```
const AutoComplete = () => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const [blur, setBlur] = useState(false);
  const radarTrends = useSelector(selectedRadarsTrends);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const filteredValue = useSelector(selectedFilteredValue);


  const debounceFilteredValue = (value) => {
      dispatch(setFilteredValue(value));
   }

  const debounce = useCallback(_.debounce(debounceFilteredValue, 300), []);

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    debounce(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    setBlur(false);
    setFocus(true);
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    setFocus(false);
    setBlur(true);
  };
  return (
    <StyledAutoComplete hasFocus={focus} hasBlur={blur}>
      <StyledMagnifier>
        <Magnifier width={20} height={20} />
      </StyledMagnifier>
      <Input
        placeholder="type trend name"
        type="text"
        label=""
        name="autocomplete"
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      />
    </StyledAutoComplete>
  );
};
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `re-render` is caused by `useSelector` after `dispatch`.

```html
When an action is dispatched, useSelector() will do a reference comparison of
the previous selector result value and the current result value.
If they are different, the component will be forced to re-render.
If they are the same, the component will not re-render.
```

See the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: I think its re-render also without any useSelector(). dispatch causes also re-rendering.

Comment: Dispatch by its own does not cause re-render. The component re-renders if it receives new props.

Comment: my component do not receive any props

Comment: @sonkamatas Do you see that my component recieve any props ? I dont have any params.

Comment: what about a parent component which encapsulates your `current` component? Where is the `altered` state used what is the yield of your dispatch. Just tryin to help.

Comment: altered state is in redux . I proved that re-rendering is caused by dispatch. I tried  to use this dispatch in parent component but it didnt help.

Comment: you were right with selectors:). They caused re-render  I put filter into separated reducer. So I solved it. Thanks :)